# How to see the properties of folder in terminal?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

How to see the properties of folder(including subfolder) in terminal as windows gives the properties like size, no of files, no of folders etc....

Comment: Better ask this on http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 6):

there are separate commands for all the things you want to do.  E.g.:

Total size:

```
du -hc FOLDER
```

number of files:

```
find FOLDER -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

number of folders:

```
find FOLDER -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```

etc. Usually, there is more than one way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: It is giving size for individual subfolder. I need for all subfolders in single instance

Comment: ah.. thanks for pointing that out. Somehow remembered that windows displays the size for all children, but the number of files is only for the current folder. If you want that for all subfolders, remove -maxdepth 1

Answer (score 3):

Use `ll` or `ls -l` to view details..

Answer (score 0):

I've also noticed that some systems will include metadata files for information that the filesystem can't natively represent. This information is displayed alongside the information the other answers can get you in your file browser's "Properties" window.

- `.directory` (Most Linux Desktops support this) [Here's the Arch Wiki page for these poorly named "Desktop Entries".](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/desktop_entries)
- `Autorun.inf` (Windows supports this)
- MacOS has one too, but I don't remember what it is.